# Better way to save removed value from array, using std.algorithm

Tags: d

I need to remove the first element from an array, that is present in a second array.

Looking through the [std.algorithm](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html) package, I can get part way there with `findAmong` and `remove`.

But is there a way to combine these, so that I can both remove an element, and see which element was removed?

For example:

```
// array that will have elements removed
auto targetStrings = ["a", "b", "c"];
// holder for element that will be removed
string removedString;
// array to match against, to determine what should be removed
auto removeStrings = ["b", "a"];

auto r = findAmong(targetStrings, removeStrings);
if (r.count > 0) {
  removedString = r[0];
  targetStrings = targetStrings.remove!(c => c == removedString);
}

writeln(removedString);
writeln(targetStrings);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the element's index by subtracting the length of the remaining range returned by `findAmong` from the length of the original range, and then just use `remove` with the index:

```
auto r = findAmong(targetStrings, removeStrings);
if (!r.empty)
{
    removedString = r.front;
    auto index = targetStrings.length - r.length;
    targetStrings = targetStrings.remove(index);
}
```

Alternatively, get the index directly with `countUntil`:

```
auto index = targetStrings.countUntil!(s => removeStrings.canFind(s));
if (index >= 0)
{
    removedString = targetStrings[index];
    targetStrings = targetStrings.remove(index);
}
```